# Where do Astronomers usually get their wavelengths? Where do they turn to look up standard, accepted values for spectral features?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, spectroscopy, data-analysis, spectrometry

When identifying isolated observed spectral features or fitting complex observed spectra or even running complex numerical simulations, one needs a reliable, standard table of known wavelengths and other parameters like splitting, intensity relationships, etc.

**Question:** Where do Astronomers usually get their wavelengths?  Are there a few favorite references where astronomers turn to look up standard, accepted values for spectral features?

Somewhat related:

- [Vacuum and air wavelengths in spectroscopy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/44999/7982)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Splatalogue](https://splatalogue.online//advanced1.php) is an excellent resource that allows you to search for spectral line transitions for a given atomic/molecular species within a specified wavelength range. It compiles data from a number of sources, including JPL, the Cologne Database for Molecular Spectroscopy (CDMS), and Lovas/NIST.

If you are looking for more detailed information than just the wavelengths, I recommended either going to [CDMS](https://cdms.astro.uni-koeln.de/cgi-bin/cdmssearch) directly, or using the Leiden Atomic And Molecular Database ([LAMDA](https://home.strw.leidenuniv.nl/%7Emoldata/)). This provides details such as Einstein A coefficients, energy levels and collisional data for a small number of key molecular species.

Comment: These are great, thanks! Do you know if Splatalog, CDMS or LAMDA are *used by astronomers* to look up standard, accepted values for spectral features? I haven't asked for a recommendation, I've asked for what sources astronomers usually use.

Comment: @uhoh I am a PhD astrophysics student, so I can only speak for myself and colleagues. But yes, we use these tools regularly. For example, Splatalogue is very helpful when putting together a telescope proposal, to identify which lines lie within a particular spectral window. Data from CDMS/LAMDA is incorporated directly into computer models to allow the gas chemistry to be accurately simulated.

Comment: Then that sounds pretty conclusive, *thanks!*